# Adempiere - How can I create notification due to certain condition through Notice?

Tags: adempiere

I have an `Internal Use Inventory` Window.

The schema process is that there are `3` people who are in charge of handling `Internal Use Inventory`.

They are `Requester`, `Andrew` and `Richard`.

When a requester request `5` items via `Internal Use Inventory` and complete the document,

The document will be delivered to `Andrew` so that he can approve it.

After document approved by `Andrew`, it'll be delivered to `Richard`. As `Logistic` man he checks whether there's enough stock or not.

Turns out the stock is only `3`. So he's not approving the document because the stock is lack.

Thus, the document status become `'Not Approved'`.

If the document `'Not Approved'`, there's a notification to `Andrew` that the document is `not Approved`
because the stock available cannot fulfill the stock requested by the User.

How can I make the notification itself ? is it through `Notice` ?

How can I make the notification through `Notice`? as I have browse the internet but I still have no idea on how to do it.

Your answer will be much appreciated, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Notices** functionality is intended for System related messaging.

For the process related messages you indicated you would use the **Workflow** processes and there are some examples in the Garden World demo customer.  The **Process_Requisition** workflow gives you a basic example of something along the lines that you requested.